# Enable 500+ rep users to "Edit" in exchange for reviewing 3-4 "Edits", when queue is full

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Disabling a feature for users, without any way to change it or help isn't the optimal solution.

This would make sure everyone can edit,
but has to review another 3-4 edits in exchange,
which assures that the amount of edits in the queue stays the same.

This "privilege" would be restricted to people who have access to other basic review privileges.

Comment: I think this would just cause users to blindly click "Approve" a few times without actually doing the reviews, just to get their edit submitted.

Comment: you could increase the audit percentage to 50% to ensure quality and ban users who fail to many audits.

Comment: which in turn  turns off reviewers...

Comment: The 50% audit percentage would be disabled for 3k+ rep users.

Answer (score 7):

I think you misunderstand the point of reviews - reviews are meant for newer users to get eased into editing, and reviewers are *experienced* users, who in theory understand the site better . In a sense, suggested reviews are as much a tool for teaching new users the 'culture' of a site, and handling their posts than anything else.

Your system essentially means you have new users, still unfamiliar with the site reviewing in exchange for getting things that need to be reviewed just pass through unreviewed, which results in even more posts reviewed by folks who arn't familiar with the site.

No matter *what* the reputation limit is, trading "suggested edits" for "suggested edit reviews" feels like the blind leading the blind. I don't disagree this can be a problem but this needs a *better class of solution*.

I'd actually suggest new users *not* edit until they feel they are familiar and can make good edits most of the time. A few early failed edits are probably not the end of the world as long as they get where they went wrong.

Comment: I have 700 rep on SO, I have access to 4 review queues, but I still can't edit anything and can't make space for edits.

Comment: SO has some... pretty unique issues like the edit queue filling up. Nonetheless, throwing open the gates isn't going to help much. Doing so just for the sake of clearing the suggested edit queue is a terrible idea IMO.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful And yet 700 rep isn't enough to review suggested edits.  That you have access to other review queues, despite having very little experience with the site, is a big reason that those queues have a lot of problems; people are using them that don't understand the site's rules, or how to use the queues.  Letting them do *more* things that they don't understand how to do properly wouldn't help.

Comment: Disabling the edit feature, just because of that, is a huge drawback though. But maybe the main culprit is that queues are bound to reputation. I'm a stack overflow member for 4-5 years, I would have had a maximum of 1500 rep +500 sacrificed for voting. I would say I'm competent enough to review edits, but I would have need another 1.5 years on SO to get that privilege.

It's just want to "edit" things and not need 2k reputation to be able to do so, that's just insane. Disable the feature completely and give it to 2k rep only, but don't give me a message I can't do anything about.